# jQuery dropdown menu won't show hidden divs

Tags: jquery, forms

There is something obvious I'm missing about this.. just trying to display hidden divs based on the value of dropdown menu...  **here's a jsfiddle:**

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vP8fP/)

and the code..

```
<p id="data"></p>  

<select id="dropdown">

      <option label="US CERT1">"#divone"</option>
      <option label="US CERT2">"#divtwo"</option>
      <option label="NIST">"#divfour"</option>
      <option label="DHS NY">"#divfive"</option>      
      <option label="DHS News">"#divsix"</option>   

  </select>

  <div id="divone" class="section" >  

     Contents of divone

  </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

   function displayVals() {
      var targetdiv = $("#dropdown").val();
      $("#data").html("<b>Var data:</b> " +  targetdiv  );
      $('.section').css('display','none');
      $(targetdiv).css('display','block');
   }

   $("select").change(displayVals);
   displayVals();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotations from your `option` values:

```
  <option label="US CERT1">#divone</option>
  <option label="US CERT2">#divtwo</option>
  <option label="NIST">#divfour</option>
  <option label="DHS NY">#divfive</option>      
  <option label="DHS News">#divsix</option>
```

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/nKL5v/

The reason being that this line:

```
$(targetdiv)
```

Is equivalent to something like `$("\"#divone\"")`, which contains an invalid selector.

Comment: thanks much for the precise input I needed..  quotes are the bane of my existence :)

Comment: @stebbin45: No problem! Glad to help. Sometimes all you need is a second pair of eyes `:)`

Comment: just a heads up that ..  this might not be a good approach to jQuery dropdown because Firefox does not seem to support select/option labels.

LINK:  [support in browsers](http://content.screencast.com/users/ssking44/folders/Snagit/media/75b7970e-114e-443c-a322-8b39519da5f4/10.02.2011-16.04.39.png) 

 -  LINK: [reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/label)